# Push local postgresql database to heroku: The local psql command could not be located

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to push a local postgresql database to my heroku project. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Postgresql works perfectly on my computer and the psql command works as well (Path is set correctly to the bin folder)!

But when I try to push my databse with

```
heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app sushi
```

(with my db name as mylocaldb and my real app name), it doesn't work at all.

Problem: The local psql command could not be located

Why? As said before, psql works fine. Even a reinstall of postgresql doesn't help.

The pull statement (see: doesn't work either because postgres always wants to authenticate as my windows user (I don't know how to change the user name when using the heroku pg:pull command, this didn't help: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling the `psql` command with its full path?

For example: `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/psql`

Or if that doesn't help, you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576064/the-local-psql-command-could-not-be-located)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't help. Like I said, psql is working. How could I add the full path to the heroku pg:push command?