# CLI isn't recognizing psql command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, heroku

I've installed the Windows version of Postgres, as explained in the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql), and when I try to call `heroku pg:psql`, I get an error saying `The local psql command could not be located`. I've tried installing Postgres inside my app directory, but that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this suggested solutions?

[The local psql command could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576064/the-local-psql-command-could-not-be-located)

The problem was a difference between the version of postgres on heroku compared to the local version. Try running `heroku pg:info` and compare it to `postgres --version`