# Can't Pull From Heroku Using Pg:Pull

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have successfully deployed my Rails app to Heroku. It is working fine but I am unable to pull the data into my local database

Local postgres database name is development

Here is my database.yaml file

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: development
  username: ambanerj
  password: *********
  host: localhost
  encoding: UTF8
   pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

 production:
   adapter: postgresql
   database: development
   host: localhost
   username: ambanerj
   password: *********
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000

 test:
   adapter: postgresql
   database: app_test
   host: localhost
   username: ambanerj
   password: *********
   pool: 5
   timeout: 5000
```

When I run the command

```
heroku pg:pull
```

I get this

```
 Usage: heroku pg:pull <REMOTE_SOURCE_DATABASE> <LOCAL_TARGET_DATABASE>

 pull from REMOTE_SOURCE_DATABASE to LOCAL_TARGET_DATABASE
 LOCAL_TARGET_DATABASE must not already exist.
```

Can anyone tell me how do I go about this one and pull data from my Heroku DB into local development database? I have tried pg:pull with the options without success

Here is what I see in my Heroku dashboard.

```
Host    ec2-54-225-101-18.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Database    dd8hgh6m3vl6t7
User    mckuffxoufgewi
Port    5432
Password    
Psql    heroku pg:psql --app immense-dawn-3007 black
URL
```

Please tell me the format of using pg:pull command with an example if possible.

P.S: I tried using Taps gem without success

Answer (score 4):

To pull `pg` remote database to your local, you need to follow following command from your app root terminal:

```
 heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_[SOME COLOR NAME] mylocaldb --app shushi
```

This command will create a new local database named “mylocaldb” and then pull data from database at DATABASE_URL from the app “sushi”. In order to prevent accidental data overwrites and loss, the local database must not exist. Read [**more**](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull)

When you do heroku config:get -a secure-gorge-4090, you should see an entry for HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_[SOME COLOR NAME]. Make sure you're using whatever that token is instead of DATABASE in your commands. [courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20301671/1047207)

Comment: Okay it worked. It created the mylocaldb database but I dont see the tables and data from Heroku. But Now I get this error

'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Are you using windows? If yes, you need to set path variable. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24741509/1047207

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added both the paths but I keep getting the same error - error 'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.