# How to push database to heroku with git bash?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, git-bash, heroku-cli

I have a problem. I am trying to push a postgresql to Heroku with the Heroku CLI, but I can't seem to get it to work. I tried the Windows Command Prompt, but it runs into the error about `'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. Git Bash freezes up when I try to run it in there. I have used this: https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/623, but they doesn't work. My problem is not really with the Command Prompt, it is that Git Bash freezes when I run the command in it.  Anyone?

I am running the command: `heroku pg:push mylocaldb DATABASE_URL`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heroku pull postgresql on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919849/heroku-pull-postgresql-on-windows)

Comment: I can't run it in Git Bash, because it freezes every time, and does not finish the command.