# Fixing psql path, getting the following error: The local psql command could not be located

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I've uninstalled and installed postgres and tried to follow the following [The local psql command could not be located](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15576064/the-local-psql-command-could-not-be-located)

but still can't get heroku pg:psql to work. I suspect that it's pointed to the wrong path but not sure how to go about fixing it.

When I run locate psql | grep /bin I get this:
WARNING: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set path for your psql command

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew the path was off but another search led me here http://yizeng.me/2015/02/09/install-and-setup-postgresql-for-ruby-on-rails-on-mac-os/ and I had to open  ~/.bash_profile and add PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin